# What is the proper way to access a variable contained within a namespace from ARM assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, arm

Normally, I can access a c variable form a S file with the following (shortened for brevity):

```
// file.c
  int _tester;

// file.S
.extern _tester;

ldr r0, = _tester    // load c variable _tester in to register0
```

However, I am unable to access this variable the same way:

```
// file.cpp
namespace earth
{
  int _tester;
}
```

I realize the name is getting mangled. The question is, can I access that variable without looking up and hardcoding the mangled name in the assembly file?

Comment: I doubt it. The whole point of higher-level languages like C++ is to take care of this for us so, if you go beyond its scope, you take on responsibilities like this.

Comment: why don't you write a simple pre-processor tool script to automatically mangle before running through the assembler?

Comment: If your assembler has built-in name mangler, yes. If it doesn't, no, you'll have to mangle it yourself.

Comment: If number of symbols aren't too many https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels

Comment: Thanks auselen, I have a very limited number of symbols, so this worked great for me.